# With Spring boot and multiple data sources how do I specify @primary outside the configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using 2 data sources defined in libraries as the configuration is shared across multiple projects.

I'm getting this error

```
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Specifying which data source is @Primary is a bit of a hack. I'd really like to just map a specific entity manager to a specific repository.

Both of the configuration files defined in the jar files are the same. Change jr to jr2 for the second configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
 entityManagerFactoryRef = "jrEntityManagerFactory",
 transactionManagerRef = "jrTransactionManager",
 basePackages = {"au.com.jr"}
)
public class PSPTrxDatasourceConfig {
    public PSPTrxDatasourceConfig() {
}

@Bean(
    name = {"jrDataSource"}
)
@ConfigurationProperties(
    prefix = "jr.datasource"
)
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(
    name = {"jrEntityManagerFactory"}
)
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean jrEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("jrDataSource") DataSource jrDataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(jrDataSource).packages(new String[]{"au.com.jr"}).persistenceUnit("jr").build();
}

@Bean(
    name = {"jrTransactionManager"}
)
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("jrEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory jrEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(jrEntityManagerFactory);
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you read through https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources ?

Comment: Docs say to use Primary. We don't have a concept of Primary and it breaks the structure of creating database library projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created a hack. There is an additional 'superfluous' data source that specifies @Primary in the local project.